# Prohibit access to base class handle in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ library and I would like to hide the name of a base class, i.e. I do not want the user to be able to use a base class pointer (or reference) to refer to the derived classes.

Let's say I have a class

```
class Message
{
  public:
  //...
};
```

and two derived classes:

```
class SpecialMessage : public Message
{
  //..
};

class NeatMessage : public Message
{
  //..
};
```

How to make it so the user can't do something like:

```
SpecialMessage specialMessage{};
Message* baseHandle = &specialMessage;
```

One reason I want to preclude this behavior is I do not want to declare the Message's destructor to be virtual.

I thought about hiding the Message in a detail namespace:

```
namespace detail
{
    class Message
    {
    };
}
```

but this is kinda weird and the user could still get to the Message class if the are so inclined.

EDIT:

Private inheritance will not work for me as I still want the user to be able to access the Message's methods (thru the derived class's object).  Neither will composition -- because in order to make the Message's methods accessible to the user I would have to write wrapper code in the derived classes.

Declaring the base class's destructor as protected (as suggested by Sebastian Redl), although an interesting idea, also will not work for me as it still allows the user to get a base class handle.

Comment: I guess you derive your SpecialMessage from Message for some implementation reuse. If so, best will be not to derive it, but keep it in private as member. If you dont want them have same virtual table.

Comment: This is done via documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could inherit privately, or you could embed a `Message` object inside `SpecialMessage` instead of deriving.

Or if you never actually need raw `Message` objects, you could make `Message`s destructor protected.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the user to be able to access the Message's methods

Comment: Write explicit using directives or forwarders.

Comment: you can Facade them. So, SpecialMessage may have same methods, as Message, and inside those methods just recall Message's methods when needs.

Comment: "make Message's destructor protected" interesting ... i think that's what I'll do.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like declaring the base class destructor protected only makes it so you can't instantiate the Message ... the user can still get a base class handle to the derived Objects

Comment: I think the protected destructor for Message is the best I'm going to get ... it still allows the user to get a base class handle, but it doesn't allow the user to destroy the object thru the base class (with delete).

Answer (score 2):

Use protected or private inheritance instead of public:

```
class SpecialMessage : private Message {};
```

Or, to solve your real problem of not having a virtual destructor, just make `Message`'s destructor protected. Then even though they can make a base class pointer, they can't non-polymorphically destroy the object through it.

I have to ask you to consider your design though: Why do you want a `Message` interface at all? If the base class is completely non-polymorphic you should absolutely use composition or private inheritance instead of public inheritance. Public inheritance is to be used only for substitution, not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). If you inherit from `Message`, there is no way I can think of to hide its declaration from the user. Of course you could obscure it, like you suggested, but the declaration has to be there - period.

If you use `Message` as a private member and don't ship the source code of your library, the user will not see the declaration. For your users to be able to access functions of `Message`, use the [facade pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to provide the semantics you require with a different architecture.  However, to work around this issue you can always do some gross template magic like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Message
{
public:
    void Foo() {}
    int Bar(int i) {return i + 10;}
};

class SpecialMessage
{
private:
    Message message;
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    auto MessageCall(T t, Args... args) -> decltype((message.*t)(args...))
    {
        return (message.*t)(args...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    SpecialMessage m;
    m.MessageCall(&Message::Foo);
    std::cout << "\n test: " << m.MessageCall(&Message::Bar, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

A little bit dirty, yeah...